# Creating a JSON object from Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to learn AppScript and I am using Google Sheets as an example. I want to create a simple JSON object using some data populated in the Sheet.

Table Example

```
Name    ID   Price   Qty
ABC     123  100      1
DEF     342   56      2
HIJ     233   90      3
IJK     213   68      5
```

I want the JSON out to be something like

```
[
  {
    "Name": "ABC",
    "ID": "123",
    "Price": 100,
    "Qty": 1
  },
  {
    "Name": "DEF",
    "ID": "342",
    "Price": 56,
    "Qty": 2
  },
  {
    "Name": "HIJ",
    "ID": "233",
    "Price": 90,
    "Qty": 3
  },
  {
    "Name": "IJK",
    "ID": "213",
    "Price": 68,
    "Qty": 5
  }
]
```

I started by following this Youtube tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TQzPIVJf6-w. However that video talks about creating each column header as a the object. Where as i want the Column name to be the `key` and the Row value to be the `value`.

Here is my current AppScript Code

```
function doGet() {
  var result={};
  var rewards = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1')
  .getDataRange()
  .getValues();

  result.rewardObj = makeObject(rewards);
  //Logger.log(result.rewardObj);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(result))
  .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)


}

function makeObject(multiArray)
{
  var obj = {}; 
  var colNames = multiArray.shift();
  var rowNames = multiArray.slice(0,1);
  var rowCount = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getLastRow();
  var colCount = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getLastColumn();

  for(var j=0;j<4;j++)
  {
    for(var i=0;i<4;i++)
      {
        //obj[colNames] = rowNames.map(function(item){return item[i];});
        obj[colNames[j][i]] = multiArray[j][i];
      }
  }
  Logger.log(rowCount)
  Logger.log(colCount)
  Logger.log(multiArray[57][12]);
  return obj;
}
```

The output is a single object

```
{"rewardObj":{"Name":"ABC","ID":"123","Price":"100","Qty":"1"}}
```

PS: I am not a programmer, I am just learning some scripting in a hackey way. Apologies for not knowing the basics :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Please try:

```
function getJsonArrayFromData(data)
{

  var obj = {};
  var result = [];
  var headers = data[0];
  var cols = headers.length;
  var row = [];

  for (var i = 1, l = data.length; i < l; i++)
  {
    // get a row to fill the object
    row = data[i];
    // clear object
    obj = {};
    for (var col = 0; col < cols; col++) 
    {
      // fill object with new values
      obj[headers[col]] = row[col];    
    }
    // add object in a final result
    result.push(obj);  
  }

  return result;  

}
```

**Test function:**

```
function test_getJsonArrayFromData()
{
  var data =   
    [
      ['Planet', 'Mainland', 'Country', 'City'],
      ['Earth', 'Europe', 'Britain', 'London'],
      ['Earth', 'Europe', 'Britain', 'Manchester'],
      ['Earth', 'Europe', 'Britain', 'Liverpool'],
      ['Earth', 'Europe', 'France', 'Paris'],
      ['Earth', 'Europe', 'France', 'Lion']
    ];

    Logger.log(getJsonArrayFromData(data));

    // =>  [{Mainland=Europe, Country=Britain, Planet=Earth, City=London}, {Mainland=Europe, Country=Britain, Planet=Earth, City=Manchester}, {Mainland=Europe, Country=Britain, Planet=Earth, City=Liverpool}, {Mainland=Europe, Country=France, Planet=Earth, City=Paris}, {Mainland=Europe, Country=France, Planet=Earth, City=Lion}]

}
```

Comment: Wow that worked beautifully. Thank you very much. I am studying the code to understand what it does. If you can add some comments, that would be super helpful. I think the major mistake I was doing was returning the Object `obj` instead of an array, correct?

Comment: Specifically, can you help explain what does this line of code mean?                  
    obj[headers[col]] = row[col];

Comment: @maverick340 it is taking the value from the first row (the headers of your columns) and setting it as the key. Then it is taking the value in whichever row you are on, and setting it as the value. Hope that helps!

Comment: @maverick340, you may use `Logger.log()` in each step, run the script and press `Ctrl + Enter` to see the log. It may help to see intermediate results.

Comment: @JordanRhea : Thanks for the initial video tutorial and the explanation.

Comment: @maverick340 Thanks for watching!

Comment: This is ultimate, awesome.. already i did a half of the same code, but this code snippet is apt to my requirement. Thanks for this simple and understandable code :)

Answer (score 9):

I know it's been a while, but I came up with a slightly more flexible solution. I've created an aptly named function that converts spreadsheet data to objects, given a set of headers and a set of rows.

```
function convertToObjects(headers, rows)
{
  return rows.reduce((ctx, row) => {
    ctx.objects.push(ctx.headers.reduce((item, header, index) => {
      item[header] = row[index];
      return item;
    }, {}));
    return ctx;
  }, { objects: [], headers}).objects;
}
```

You can call the above function like this:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('YourSheetName');
var [headers, ...rows] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var objects = convertToObjects(headers, rows);
```

If you need to ignore the first row and get headers from the second row (like I do), then you can do this instead:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('YourSheetName');
var [_, headers, ...rows] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var objects = convertToObjects(headers, rows);
```

If you have any improvements to this, please let me know in the comments below.

Comment: Super helpful! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

### edit 2022 : for headers of columns and headers of rows as follows

| yourJsonName | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| row1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |  |
| row2 | 4 |  | 6 | 4 |
| row3 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 8 |

try

```
function myJson() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('YourSheetName');
  var [headers, ...rows] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var jsonString = `var ${sheet.getRange(1,1).getValue()} = ${JSON.stringify(data2json(headers, rows))}`
  Logger.log (jsonString)
}
function data2json(headers, rows) {
  var obj = {},items = {};
  for (var i in rows) {
    obj = {};
    for (var col = 1; col < headers.length; col++) {
      if(rows[i][col]!='') obj[headers[col]] = rows[i][col];
    }
    items[rows[i][0]] = obj
  }
  return items;
}
```

```js
var [headers, ...rows] = [['yourJsonName', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'], ['row1', 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, ], ['row2', 4.0, , 6.0, 4.0], ['row3', 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 8.0]]
console.log (`var ${headers[0]} = ${JSON.stringify(data2json(headers, rows))}`)
function data2json(headers, rows) {
  var obj = {},items = {};
  for (var i in rows) {
    obj = {};
    for (var col = 1; col < headers.length; col++) {
      if(rows[i][col]!='') obj[headers[col]] = rows[i][col];
    }
    items[rows[i][0]] = obj
  }
  return items;
}
```

with saving in drive ... adapt names as necessary (YourSheetName, YourFolderName, YourFileName)

```
function myJson() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('YourSheetName');
  var [headers, ...rows] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var jsonString = `var ${sheet.getRange(1,1).getValue()} = ${JSON.stringify(data2json(headers, rows))}`
  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('YourFolderName');
  if (folders.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folders.next();
    saveData(folder, 'YourFileName.json',jsonString);
  }
}
function data2json(headers, rows) {
  var obj = {},items = {};
  for (var i in rows) {
    obj = {};
    for (var col = 1; col < headers.length; col++) {
      if(rows[i][col]!='') obj[headers[col]] = rows[i][col];
    }
    items[rows[i][0]] = obj
  }
  return items;
}
function saveData(folder, fileName, content) {
  var children = folder.getFilesByName(fileName);
  var file = null;
  if (children.hasNext()) {
    file = children.next();
    file.setContent(content);
  } else {
    file = folder.createFile(fileName, content);
  }
  Logger.log(file.getUrl())
}
```