# Creating a nested JSON object with Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to teach myself some AppScript/Javascript. As an exercise, I am want to generate the following JSON object

```
[
  {
    "config_type": "City Details",
    "config_data": [
      {
        "city_type": "MAJOR_CITY",
        "city_data": [
          {
            "city_name": "BIGFOOLA",
            "monetary_data": [
              {
                "currency_data": [
                  {
                    "dollars": 1000
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to be able to enter only few details like "City Details", "MAJOR_CITY", and the dollar value - 1000 in a Google Sheet. The script should be able to generate the above JSON.

So I started by creating the names of all the Arrays and Objects in one row. In front of the the arrays, there was a blank cell and in front of the object the value. The Sheet looks like this

```
A              B 
config_type    City Details
config_data    
city_type      MAJOR_CITY
city_data
city_name      BIGFOOLA
monetary_data
currency_data
dollars        1000
```

I am able to get all of the details in a single object, but struggling to nest them under each other. How do I go about this?

Edit :Here is what I have for now

```
function doGet(){
  var result={}
  var rewardSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("CITY")
  var reward_data = rewardSheet.getRange("A1:B13").getValues();

  result = getJsonArrayFromData(reward_data);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(result))
  .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
}


function getJsonArrayFromData(data)
{
  var column_headers = data[0];
  var col_len = column_headers.length;
  var row = [];
  var reward_obj = [];
  var config_obj = {};

  var config_type = {};
  var config_data = [];
  var reward_type = {};
  var reward_data = [];
  var reward_name = {};
  var reward_data_2 = [];
  var currency_data = [];
  var curreny_obj = {};
  var rewardSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("CITY")
  var row_items = rewardSheet.getRange(1,1,data.length,1).getValues();
  //Logger.log(row_items);

  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){

    row = data [i];
    config_type ={};
    reward_type[config_type]={};
    reward_name[reward_type]={};

    //Logger.log(row);
    for(var r=0;r<row.length;r++)
    {
      config_type[row[r]] = row[r+1];
      reward_type[row[r]] = row[r+1];
      reward_name[row[r]] = row[r+1];

    }
    config_data.push(config_type,reward_type,reward_name);
    //reward_data.push(reward_name);


    reward_obj = config_data;
  } 
  Logger.log(reward_obj);


  return reward_obj;

}
```

Ps: I know the JSON is messy, but its just to understand and teach myself.

Comment: Try to write the code yourself, then if are not able to make it work, search/research about what are you trying to do, then if you don't find how to do this, make a question. If you already did this, include a [mcve]. Reference [ask].

Comment: Related: [Creating a JSON object from Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47555347/1595451)

Comment: Sure, i will add what I have. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

You hard-coded a bunch of property names as variables; this is not a good approach.

Here is how one can do this. The variable `output` holds the object we'll return at the end, while `currentObject` points to the object that is due to be filled next. When it comes to filling it, we either have a scalar value `data[i][1]` to put in, or we don't, in which case a new object is created and becomes the new currentObject.

```
function formJSON() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("CITY");
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var currentObject = {};
  var output = [currentObject];                     // or just currentObject  
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][1]) {
      currentObject[data[i][0]] = data[i][1];
    }
    else {
      var newObject = {};
      currentObject[data[i][0]] = [newObject];      // or just newObject 
      currentObject = newObject;
    }
  }
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(output));
}
```

The output is

```
[{"config_type":"City Details","config_data":[{"city_type":"MAJOR_CITY","city_data":[{"city_name":"BIGFOOLA","monetary_data":[{"currency_data":[{"dollars":1000}]}]}]}]}]
```

or, in beautified form,

```
[{
  "config_type": "City Details",
  "config_data": [{
    "city_type": "MAJOR_CITY",
    "city_data": [{
      "city_name": "BIGFOOLA",
      "monetary_data": [{
        "currency_data": [{
          "dollars": 1000
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }]
}]
```

Incidentally, I don't see why you wanted to put every object in an array. A property can be another object. Removing square brackets on the commented lines we would get

```
{
  "config_type": "City Details",
  "config_data": {
    "city_type": "MAJOR_CITY",
    "city_data": {
      "city_name": "BIGFOOLA",
      "monetary_data": {
        "currency_data": {
          "dollars": 1000
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @user6655984. Can you do the reverse? Which is to import JSON into Sheets. One problem is I am not sure the best way to have JSON in Sheets.