# Add more values in var while "X value" is lower than Y

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to do a JSON Array using 3 or 4 colums but I can't fill the data using the "while" condition.

I have some Google Sheet Data which can have 3 or 4 columns, this data must be inside a JSON Array, for example:

```
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|      variable       |     condition    |        value        |      and/or      |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|         CPC         |        >         |         100         |                  |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
```

In this first example the 4th column is empty because we only have one row of data, so, the result must be:
["CPC",">",100]

if we have two rows (or more) of data, this should look like this:

```
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|      variable       |     condition    |        value        |      and/or      |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|         CPC         |        >         |         100         |       and        |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|     s_volume        |        <         |         950         |       and        |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|      s_volume       |        >         |         100         |                  |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
```

as you can see, the last row in the last column is empty, and the result should look like this:

["CPC",">",100],
"and",
["s_volume","<",950],
"and",
["s_volume",">",100]

Finally, this JSON array must me assigned to a variable.

I have tried with this:

```
//Get values from cells 
 var fil1 = ss.getSheetByName("app").getRange(row,4,1,1).getValue();
 var fil2 = ss.getSheetByName("app").getRange(row,5,1,1).getValue();
 var fil3 = ss.getSheetByName("app").getRange(row,6,1,1).getValue();
 var fil4 = ss.getSheetByName("app").getRange(row,7,1,1).getValue();

  //Count how many rows with data exist
  var coldat = ss.getSheetByName("app").getRange("D1:D").getValues();
  var coldats = coldat.filter(String).length;

  var jsonarr =  [fil1, fil2, fil3]
  //loop para añadir nuevos filtros
   while (row < coldats) {
   fil4,[fil1,fil2,fil3];
    row++;
  };
```

Apparently with my code the var "jsonarr" is filled only with the first row, ignoring any number of rows below.

I have tried with several tutorials and array methods to make this JSON Object, but I just can't get the correct answer. I really sorry for this newbie question, I'm not expert in coding, just a geek that do some work and is learning the very basics.

Comment: How much research have you done? Have you read [Creating a JSON object from Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47555347). However, it seems to me that you are putting too much effort into _how to create_ the JSON array and not enough effort into building raw data and the structure layout of the JSON. Your description of JSON is confusing; please give an example of the JSON output that you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a JSON object from Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47555347/creating-a-json-object-from-google-sheets)

Comment: As I explain, the output that I want is more like this:
[ [column1,column2,column3], column4, [column1,column2,column3] ], in this case, column 1, 2 and 3 are the values inside [ ], and the column 4 connects those values inside [ ]. Column 4 is not always visible, it should be in the result only if there are 2 or more rows of data and if is not the last value. The answer in the URL that you share doesn't let me do that (or I just couldn't do it).

Comment: That is not valid JSON. Validate your JSON [JSONLint, maybe](https://jsonlint.com), and then give an example of your JSON.

Comment: Yes, I know that this is not exactly a valid JSON, but that's how this API wants the information. For example, I should request the information like this:

{
 "data" : {
  "1" : {
   "country_code" : "ES", 
   "depth" : 2, 
   "offset" : 0, 
   "limit" : 5, 
   "language" : "es", 
   "filters" : [["cpc",">",1],"or", ["search_volume",">",1],"or",[ "key","<>","sinonimos"] ], 
   "keyword" : "hermano"
   }
   }
   } 

The filters variable is the last thing I just need to generate from the cells, and follows that structure.

Comment: Var "jsonarr" has only one row of data because the "row" value in `fil1`-`fil4` returns only ONE row. You need to do three things. 1) work out how many rows of data that you have, 2) get ALL the data, then 3) use the row count to loop through the rows one by one, and build your array. There are plenty of examples of this on StackOverflow; I mentioned one earlier and [Creating a nested JSON object with Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47577712/) is another. FWIW, your row `var jsonarr =  [fil1, fil2, fil3]` works fine but `fil4,[fil1,fil2,fil3];` does nothing.

Comment: Any help? I have tried to figure this out with too many tutorials, I still can't create the exact output that I want.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is offered to assist the OP to bring together a range of issues identified in the OP's original code. I have left a number of Logger statements in the answer code that the OP can use to identify values at different stages of the code, assist with troubleshooting, and as an aid to skill development.

The results of the code is contained in the variable `fildata`. Based on the sample data, the value is:
`["CPC",">",100],"and",["s_volume","<",950],"and",["s_volume",">",100]`
How this is exported is up to the OP.

The OP is trying to create a data array (non-complying JSON) for data in a spreadsheet as input to another system.

The design of the OP's code meant that it retrieved only one row of data, and it could never build up the array as expected. The OP's code is the basis of the answer, but there are several key changes:

1. Moved `coldat` and `coldats` to the top of the code so that the `coldats` could be used in defining the data range.
2. Retrieved a single data range (`getRange(2, 4, coldats, 4)`) and used 'getValues()' only once.
3. Created a variable to hold the results of code
4. Looped through the data row-by-row
5. For each row, evaluated whether Column G ("and/or" column) contained a value. Depending on the result, included Column G in the results for that row.
6. Built up the results by row-by-row increment.

---

```
function so54394711() {

  // setup spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("app");

  //Count how many rows with data exist
  var coldat = sheet.getRange("D2:D").getValues();
  var coldats = coldat.filter(String).length;
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: Number of rows of data = "+coldats); //DEBUG

  // establish the data range and values
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 4, coldats, 4);
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: range = "+range.getA1Notation());//DEBUG
  var values = range.getValues();
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: values: "+ values);//DEBUG

  // create a variable to hold the results
  var fildata = "";

  //loop through the data by row, build the results line-by-line
  for (i = 0; i < coldats; i++) {
    var filD = values[i][0];
    var filE = values[i][1];
    var filF = values[i][2];
    var filG = values[i][3];

    // test if column G contains a value
    if (filG.length == 0) {
      // array is empty
      fildata += '[' + '"' + filD + '","' + filE + '",' + filF + ']';
      //Logger.log("DEBUG: G=MT, fildata = "+fildata);//DEBUG
    } else {
      //array not empty
      fildata += '[' + '"' + filD + '","' + filE + '",' + filF + ']' + ',"' + filG + '",';
      //Logger.log("DEBUG: G<>MT, fildata = "+fildata);//DEBUG
    }
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: fildata = "+fildata);//DEBUG   
  }
}
```