# get column names and its values in object where values for Column1 are dynamic

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a following kind of spreadsheet where there are two columns but the number of rows where user can able to input value can be dynamic. I mean user might input 10 values for sub-column1 or 20. When user hits the submit button after filling the data, the script should create the following object

```
"data": {
    "Column1": [
        {
            subcolumn1: 100,
            subcolumn2: 200,
            subcolumn3: 300
        },
        {
            subcolumn1: 400,
            subcolumn2: 500,
            subcolumn3: 600
        },
        {
            subcolumn1: 700,
            subcolumn2: 800,
            subcolumn3: 900
        },
    ],
    "Column2": {
        column2a: 100,
        column2b: 20
    }
}
```

[image]

for now, i could only get the sheet using app script

```
function testCalculation() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var sheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeSheet = sheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var column = 2;
  var lastRow = activeSheet.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = activeSheet.getLastColumn();
  var searchRange = activeSheet.getRange(4, 1, lastRow-4+1, lastColumn);
  var rangeArray = searchRange.getValues();
  var data = rangeArray;
  var headers = data.shift();
  Logger.log(headers);
  var result = {}
  var subHeaders = data.shift();
  var row = [];
  var finalResult = [];
  for (var i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++) {
    Logger.log(data[i]);
    row=data[i];
    result = {}
    for (var col=0; col < subHeaders.length; col++ ) { 
      result[subHeaders[col]] = row[col]
    }
    finalResult.push(result);
  }
  Logger.log(finalResult);
}
```

here is the spreadsheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1534Nf5Mr-kivX-swcqdganNza6EtwDIps9nOzJhjzWc/edit#gid=0

UPDATE

I am getting the following object now

```
[
  {
    "subcolumn1": 100,
    "subcolumn2": 200,
    "subcolumn3": 300,
    "column2a": 100,
    "column2b": 20
  },
  {
    "subcolumn1": 400,
    "subcolumn2": 500,
    "subcolumn3": 600,
    "column2a": "",
    "column2b": ""
  },
  {
    "subcolumn1": 700,
    "subcolumn2": 800,
    "subcolumn3": 900,
    "column2a": "",
    "column2b": ""
  }
]
```

Sorry, the access was private before but now it is public.

how can i create above object now?

Comment: Use `getLastRow()` ([ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)) with `getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)` ([ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows-numcolumns)) to manage the dynamic number of rows. Say, `var LR = sheet.getLastRow();` - will give you the number of rows; then, say, `var range = sheet.getRange(6, 1, LR-6+1, 5);` (starts at row 6, covers as many rows as the user creates. Then `var data = range.getValues();` delivers the data in the range.

Comment: @Tedinoz thanks for your help. I got the values but how do i map those values in an object like I have mentioned in my question.

Comment: @Tedinoz I have granted the public access for that sheet. Can you help me in creating above object, please?

Comment: I am working on it, perhaps others are too-available time is an issue at present. Creating the dataset is the next challenge; it seems to me that 'Column1' needs to be built separately from 'Column 2', and that the two are then "combined" - I've been looking at [Creating a JSON object from Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47555347/1330560), both the OP's code and the answer from @MaxMakhrov.

Comment: Thank you for your kind effort. I am also trying to create json but its too challenging

Comment: did your code show {Column1: [{}], Column2: {} } ? I mean is it divided by Column1 and Column2 key as in question ? Just asking if i miss it.

Comment: I thought `{subcolumn1=100.0, subcolumn3=300.0, subcolumn2=200.0}, {subcolumn1=400.0, subcolumn3=600.0, subcolumn2=500.0}, {subcolumn1=700.0, subcolumn3=900.0, subcolumn2=800.0}` are grouped into Column1 key also. I will try this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were two issues involved in developing this answer.

- allowing for a dynamic number of rows in the "Column 1" range.
  This was done by using `getLastRow()` to buiuld the data range - this will automatically adapt to the number of rows created by the user.
- create output in the layout required by the OP.
  The previous topics [Creating a JSON object from Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47555347/creating-a-json-object-from-google-sheets) and [Creating a nested JSON object with Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47577712/creating-a-nested-json-object-with-google-sheets) provided the approach to be taken.

---

```
function so578199890602() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetname = "Sheet1";
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);

  var startRow = 5;
  var LR = sheet.getLastRow();

  // Build Column 1
  var option = 0;
  var range = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, LR-startRow+1, 3);
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: Column 1 range = "+range.getA1Notation());
  var col1data = range.getValues();
  var col1output = sogetJsonArrayFromData(col1data,option);
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(col1output));

  // Build Column 2
  var option = 1;
  var range = sheet.getRange(startRow, 4, 2, 2);
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: Column 2 range = "+range.getA1Notation());
  var col2data = range.getValues();
  var col2output = sogetJsonArrayFromData(col2data,option);
  // Logger.log(JSON.stringify(col2output));

  // join "Column 1" and Column 2"
  var finaloutput = {};
  finaloutput["Column1"] = col1output;
  finaloutput["Column2"] = col2output;
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(finaloutput))

}


function sogetJsonArrayFromData(data,option)
{

  var obj = {};
  var result = [];
  var headers = data[0];
  var cols = headers.length;
  var row = [];

  for (var i = 1, l = data.length; i < l; i++)
  {
    // get a row to fill the object
    row = data[i];
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: row = "+row)
    // clear object
    obj = {};
    for (var col = 0; col < cols; col++) 
    {
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: header: "+headers[col]+", value: "+row[col]);
      // fill object with new values
      obj[headers[col]] = row[col];    
    }
    if (option == 0){
      // option = 0 means processing Column 1
      // add object in a final result
      result.push(obj); 
    }

  }

  if (option ==0 ){
    // option = 0 means processing Column 1
    return result; 
  }
  else {
    // option <>0 means processing Column B
    return obj;
  }
}


----------
**Output**

{
    "Column1":
        [
            {
                "subcolumn1":100,
                "subcolumn2":200,
                "subcolumn3":300
            },
            {
                "subcolumn1":400,
                "subcolumn2":500,
                "subcolumn3":600
            },
            {
                "subcolumn1":700,
                "subcolumn2":800,
                "subcolumn3":900
            }
        ],
    "Column2":{
        "column2a":100,
        "column2b":20
    }
}
```

---

**Credit:** Max Makhrov - `sogetJsonArrayFromData` adapted from [Creating a JSON object from Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47555347/creating-a-json-object-from-google-sheets)